# Shimano road bike lever leaking mineral oil

Tags: road-bike, shimano, disc-brake, brake-levers

I have a leak in my Shimano DA 9170 (right) shifter. When I do a bleed, everything seems to work for a ride or two and then I start to lose braking power and the underside of the brake hood is wet with mineral oil.

Upon further inspection, I found this open port. On the other lever, this port has a black cover with a material similar to electrical tape.

Note: this is not the port with the bleed screw. That is further back on this model

Any advice?[image]

Comment: When did the leaks start? Was there any event that can be associated with the starting of the leaks? What was the reason for the first bleed?

Comment: Try refilling the system and squeezing the lever with the hood pulled back. Is the oil leaking from that hole, or somewhere else? Also, perhaps related: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/85559/shimano-dura-ace-r9120-lever-leaking